# modeling demand/elasticity for products with potential/occasional zero demand

Tags: regression, modeling, econometrics, elasticity

Looking at the [methodology](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings13/425-2013.pdf) which uses this log model:

$Log{Demand_A} = \beta_0+ \beta_1logPrice_A + \beta_2logPrice_B + \beta_3Promo_1 + \beta_4Promo_2 + \beta_5logPrice_A*Promo_1 + \beta_6*logPrice_A*Promo_2$

How would this work for training data with the occasional zero demand (log of zero is infinite). Should one just use very large negative values in the training data?

Comment: Can you summarise what was written in the methodology you linked?  We want these posts to be self-contained

Comment: I think the regression formula above should suffice.